# How to implement SearchView with ListView using custom object arraylist?

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview

I have a custom listview, which contains an object type Arraylist, and on this same activity I have a SearchView, how to search and display only the objects according to the keywords eg getName (), getCity () , ...
Here my code, my onResume

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
ArrayList<User> users;
    searchBar = findViewById(R.id.maBtnSearch);

        db = new DatabaseUser(this); 
        users = db.getData(); 

        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, users); 
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        searchBar.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

This is my adapter class:

```
    package com.example.mickael.gestioclientel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by MICKAEL on 02/12/2017.
 */

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<User> users; //Lui transmettre le tableau adapter
    private DatabaseUser db;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users){
        super(context, R.layout.design_list_user, users); //Lui transmettre le layout design de ta listeview
        db = new DatabaseUser(context);
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.users = users;
    }


    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView name, phone, date;
        ImageView btnDial, btnMap, menuPoint;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null){
            //Reglage general
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.design_list_user, parent, false); //Layout du design

            //Recuperation des ID
            viewHolder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.luPrenom);
            viewHolder.phone = convertView.findViewById(R.id.maTxtNumber);
            viewHolder.btnDial = convertView.findViewById(R.id.maBtnDial);
            viewHolder.btnMap = convertView.findViewById(R.id.maBtnMap);
            viewHolder.menuPoint = convertView.findViewById(R.id.luTrois);
            viewHolder.date = convertView.findViewById(R.id.maAdd);

            //Definition du tag
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Definition des changements
        final User user = users.get(position);

        //On regle la taille du nom selon les caractere
        if(user.getName().length() == 15){
            viewHolder.name.setTextSize(24);
        }else if(user.getName().length() == 16){
            viewHolder.name.setTextSize(23);
        }else if(user.getName().length() == 17){
            viewHolder.name.setTextSize(22);
        }else if(user.getName().length() > 18){
            viewHolder.name.setTextSize(21);
        }
        viewHolder.name.setText(user.getName()); //Definition du nom


        //Definition de lajout ou modification
        String addOrUpdate = "Modifie le";
        viewHolder.date.setText(addOrUpdate + " " + user.getDate()); //Definition de la date
        viewHolder.date.setTextSize(15);



        //TODO Je dois regler ce probleme de zero ci dessous
        String phone = String.valueOf(user.getPhone());
        if(phone.equals("93260")){
            phone = "No number phone";
            viewHolder.phone.setTextSize(16);
        }else{
            phone = "0" + phone;
            viewHolder.phone.setTextSize(20);
        }
        viewHolder.phone.setText(phone);


        //OnClick sur les boutons
        viewHolder.btnDial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        //TODO ICI Aussi Je dois regler ce probleme de zero ci dessous
                        Uri.parse("tel:0" + user.getPhone()));
                context.startActivity(intent); //Laligne la plus importante!!
            }
        });

        viewHolder.btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adressMap(); //Fonction appel de louverture des map
            }
            public void adressMap() {
                String adress = user.getAdresse();
                String txtFind = " ";
                String txtReplace= "+";
                String tmp;

                int lgFind = txtFind.length();

                for (int k = 0; k < adress.length(); k++) {
                    try {
                        tmp = adress.substring(k, k + lgFind);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if ( tmp.equalsIgnoreCase(txtFind) ) {
                        adress = adress.substring(0, k) + txtReplace + adress.substring(k + lgFind,adress.length());
                    }
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +adress+ "+" + user.getCity()));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } //Remplacement des espace par des "+"
        }); //Pour lancer la navigation



        //le menu a 3 points
        viewHolder.menuPoint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                menuTroisPoint(viewHolder, user);
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    public void menuTroisPoint(ViewHolder viewHolder, final User user) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, viewHolder.menuPoint);

        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Intent intent;
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.menu_delete:
                        //Si il selectionne Delete on lui apparait un popup de securite
                        dialogConfirmDelete(user);
                        break;
                    case R.id.menu_edit:
                        intentPageEdit(user); //Vers la page dedition
                        break;
                    case R.id.menu_send:
                        popupSendSMS();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }

    public void popupSendSMS() {
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder cBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_sms, null);

        RadioGroup rg = mView.findViewById(R.id.cdsRadioGroup);
        EditText inputPers = mView.findViewById(R.id.cdsInputPers);

        int radioId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        if (radioId == R.id.cdsRadioPers) { //Cest le ID du RADIO LUI MEME
            inputPers.setEnabled(true); //TODO CORRIGER CE PROBLEME
        }

        cBuilder.setView(mView);
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = cBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void dialogConfirmDelete(final User user) {
        AlertDialog.Builder popupSure = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); //On creer la fenetre
        popupSure.setTitle("Delete"); //Le titre de l'alerte
        popupSure.setMessage("Are you sure?");

        popupSure.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);  //Option cancel
        //Option OK
        popupSure.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //On supprime lutilisateur selon le ID
                delete(user);
            }
        });  //Option ok
        popupSure.show(); //On fait apparaitre le popup
    }

    public void delete(User user) {
        db.delete((int)user.getId());
        Toast.makeText(context, "" + user.getName() + " deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity)context).finish();
    } //Supprimer un user

    public void intentPageEdit(User user) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(context, AddUserActivity.class);
        Bundle args = new Bundle(); //On creer le bundle car cest un objet
        args.putSerializable("user", (user)); //On pose les donnees de l'intent pour le convertir en bundle en tant que objet
        intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", args); //On place les donnes enregistrer dans l'intent quon fera passe
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } //Aller vers la page dedition


}
```

up
Thanks help me please
Thanks help me please
Thanks help me please
Thanks help me please

Comment: post your adapter class as well

Comment: its simple make a method in adapter class for filtered data and then call it in fragment/activity class

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: Look my adapter class

Comment: go through this example please

Answer (score 0):

Make one more `arraylist` in your adapter class and make your adapter `implements Filterable`, try changing your adapter like below :

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable{

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<User> users; 
private ArrayList<User> usersFilter;
private DatabaseUser db;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users){
    super(context, R.layout.design_list_user, users); //Lui transmettre le layout design de ta listeview
    db = new DatabaseUser(context);
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.users = users;
    this.usersFilter= users;
}


private class ViewHolder{
    TextView name, phone, date;
    ImageView btnDial, btnMap, menuPoint;
}

 @Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            String charString = charSequence.toString();

            if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                users= usersFilter;
            } else {

                ArrayList<User> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (User user: usersFilter) {

                    if ( user.getYourField().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                        filteredList.add(user);
                    }
                }

                users= filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = users;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            users= (ArrayList<User>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null){
        //Reglage general
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.design_list_user, parent, false); //Layout du design

        //Recuperation des ID
        viewHolder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.luPrenom);
        viewHolder.phone = convertView.findViewById(R.id.maTxtNumber);
        viewHolder.btnDial = convertView.findViewById(R.id.maBtnDial);
        viewHolder.btnMap = convertView.findViewById(R.id.maBtnMap);
        viewHolder.menuPoint = convertView.findViewById(R.id.luTrois);
        viewHolder.date = convertView.findViewById(R.id.maAdd);

        //Definition du tag
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //Definition des changements
    final User user = users.get(position);

    //On regle la taille du nom selon les caractere
    if(user.getName().length() == 15){
        viewHolder.name.setTextSize(24);
    }else if(user.getName().length() == 16){
        viewHolder.name.setTextSize(23);
    }else if(user.getName().length() == 17){
        viewHolder.name.setTextSize(22);
    }else if(user.getName().length() > 18){
        viewHolder.name.setTextSize(21);
    }
    viewHolder.name.setText(user.getName()); //Definition du nom


    //Definition de lajout ou modification
    String addOrUpdate = "Modifie le";
    viewHolder.date.setText(addOrUpdate + " " + user.getDate()); //Definition de la date
    viewHolder.date.setTextSize(15);



    //TODO Je dois regler ce probleme de zero ci dessous
    String phone = String.valueOf(user.getPhone());
    if(phone.equals("93260")){
        phone = "No number phone";
        viewHolder.phone.setTextSize(16);
    }else{
        phone = "0" + phone;
        viewHolder.phone.setTextSize(20);
    }
    viewHolder.phone.setText(phone);


    //OnClick sur les boutons
    viewHolder.btnDial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    //TODO ICI Aussi Je dois regler ce probleme de zero ci dessous
                    Uri.parse("tel:0" + user.getPhone()));
            context.startActivity(intent); //Laligne la plus importante!!
        }
    });

    viewHolder.btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adressMap(); //Fonction appel de louverture des map
        }
        public void adressMap() {
            String adress = user.getAdresse();
            String txtFind = " ";
            String txtReplace= "+";
            String tmp;

            int lgFind = txtFind.length();

            for (int k = 0; k < adress.length(); k++) {
                try {
                    tmp = adress.substring(k, k + lgFind);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    break;
                }
                if ( tmp.equalsIgnoreCase(txtFind) ) {
                    adress = adress.substring(0, k) + txtReplace + adress.substring(k + lgFind,adress.length());
                }
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +adress+ "+" + user.getCity()));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } //Remplacement des espace par des "+"
    }); //Pour lancer la navigation



    //le menu a 3 points
    viewHolder.menuPoint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            menuTroisPoint(viewHolder, user);
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}

public void menuTroisPoint(ViewHolder viewHolder, final User user) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, viewHolder.menuPoint);

    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.menu_delete:
                    //Si il selectionne Delete on lui apparait un popup de securite
                    dialogConfirmDelete(user);
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_edit:
                    intentPageEdit(user); //Vers la page dedition
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_send:
                    popupSendSMS();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}

public void popupSendSMS() {
    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder cBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_sms, null);

    RadioGroup rg = mView.findViewById(R.id.cdsRadioGroup);
    EditText inputPers = mView.findViewById(R.id.cdsInputPers);

    int radioId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    if (radioId == R.id.cdsRadioPers) { //Cest le ID du RADIO LUI MEME
        inputPers.setEnabled(true); //TODO CORRIGER CE PROBLEME
    }

    cBuilder.setView(mView);
    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = cBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

public void dialogConfirmDelete(final User user) {
    AlertDialog.Builder popupSure = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); //On creer la fenetre
    popupSure.setTitle("Delete"); //Le titre de l'alerte
    popupSure.setMessage("Are you sure?");

    popupSure.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);  //Option cancel
    //Option OK
    popupSure.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //On supprime lutilisateur selon le ID
            delete(user);
        }
    });  //Option ok
    popupSure.show(); //On fait apparaitre le popup
}

public void delete(User user) {
    db.delete((int)user.getId());
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + user.getName() + " deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity)context).finish();
} //Supprimer un user

public void intentPageEdit(User user) {
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(context, AddUserActivity.class);
    Bundle args = new Bundle(); //On creer le bundle car cest un objet
    args.putSerializable("user", (user)); //On pose les donnees de l'intent pour le convertir en bundle en tant que objet
    intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", args); //On place les donnes enregistrer dans l'intent quon fera passe
    context.startActivity(intent);
} //Aller vers la page dedition


}
```

**NOTE**  : Replace `user.getYourField()` with whatever field in your `User` class to check against the filter text you passed into the adapter

Comment: Thans but I have an error on this line why?
         final User user = users.get (position);

Comment: @MICKAELBELHASSEN remove final User user = users.get (position); , user is already assigned in constructor and rename all user variable to users inside getview()

Comment: Does not work, same error.. i have changed to this: final User users = this.users.get(position);

Comment: That's not what I asked to do remove the above line and in places where there are errors rename user to users

Comment: I deleted the line and instead, I called this way for example users.get (position) .getName (). It still does not work

Comment: The code filters, but of which it filters until to raise the search, it plants with this error. Maybe I have to do a try catch and ignore the error? If so how and where

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160871/discussion-between-mickael-belhassen-and-navneet-krishna).